# Is 0 considered true in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is 0 considered true in ES6? Or all strings considered true?

this is returning true:

```
var value = "0";
var isTrue = value ? true : false; // true
```

I thought === was for strict equality.

If it has changed is there a way to get the old way for compatibility sake?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks. The value I'm receiving will always be a string so I'll check for "0" and "false":

```
var booleanValue = value && value!=="0" && value!=="false" ? true : false;
```

Comment: here "0" is string

Comment: That's a string not an integer.

Comment: The rule enumerates what is falthy, the rest is truthy.

Comment: @justDan In my case I'll always be receiving a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a list of all falsy values in javascript:

- false
- 0
- '' or ""
- null
- undefined
- NaN

Only the String '' is a falsy value, meaning that it is an empty string.
'0' is a string with content so it isn't a falsy value, but 0 is one.

Answer (score 6):

"0" is true because it's just a string and has a value, but the 0 as a number is considered false

Answer (score 3):

All strings that have characters in them are truthy.¹ Only the empty string, `""`, is falsy.¹

`0` (the number) is falsy. `"0"` is not.

> I thought === was for strict equality.

It is. There is no `===` check in your code. The conditional operator (`? :`) doesn't do an `===` check on the condition operand. It does a boolean check, just like `if` does.

If you used `===`, it you'd get `false`:

```
var isTrue = value === true ? true : false; // false
```

Of course, in that case, there's no point to the conditional operator:

```
var isTrue = value === true; // false
```

---

> The value I'm receiving will always be a string so I'll check for "0" and "false":
>
> ```
> var booleanValue = value && value!=="0" && value!=="false" ? true : false;
> ```

It depends on what you want to do and what possible values you might get. For instance, if what you're getting will be a string containing a valid number or a valid boolean (as seems the case from your example there), you could use `JSON.parse` to parse it to a number or boolean:

```
var isTrue = !!JSON.parse(str);
```

(The `!!` is so that `0` and `NaN` convert to `false` and a number that isn't `0` or `NaN` converts to `true`.) But again, it depends on what you're receiving, a switch with the values you're expecting may be better, etc.

---

¹ "falsy" and "truthy":

- "falsy" - coerces to `false` when used as a boolean, such as in a conditional operator as in your question. The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, and of course, `false`.
- "truthy" - coerces to `true` when used as a boolean. All non-falsy values are truthy, including `"0"` and `"false"`.

Comment: I didn't use strict equality so I was counting on loose equality. My error was that "0" as a string is not considered false.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - And you're not the first to make it. :-) The one that often gets people is `"false"` being truthy.

Answer (score 1):

You're inspecting a `string` containing 0 instead of an actual `number` 0.

```
"0"  // string
0 // number
```

A `string` is considered `false` if it is equal to `''`, all other strings are considered `true`

A `number` is considered `false` if it is either `0` or `NaN`, all other numbers are considered `true`.

`===` indeed means strict equal, meaning a comparison is made on both type and value. So:

```
true == 1  // true
true === 1 // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its other way around, for any string, it will return True, for 0 as an integer, it will return False, and for 1 as an integer, it will return True

```js
var value0 = 0;
var value1 = 1;
var str = "23123";

var isTrue0 = value0 ? true : false;
var isTrue1 = value1 ? true : false; 
var isTrueStr = str ? true : false; 

console.log('0: ' + isTrue0);
console.log('1: ' + isTrue1);
console.log('string: ' + isTrueStr);
```

Answer (score -2):

isTrue = value - classic error using assignment rather than comparison.